# Find mean and SE of different variables

Tags: r, mean

For the data below, I would like to split the data into 2 groups based on their region (Mid.East/East.Asia).

Then, I would like to get the mean and SE of the 3 demographic indicators: lifeExp, gdpPercap and pop for the 2 groups in each year.

I am not sure how to go about finding the SE and mean together. So far, I am only able to calculate the mean using this:

```
df1 %>%
group_by(year) %>%
summarize(across(where( is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE) )
```

Data:

```
structure(list(country = c("Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", 
"Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", 
"Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", 
"Hong Kong, China", "Hong Kong, China", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", 
"Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", 
"Iran", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", 
"Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Iraq", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", 
"Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Kuwait", 
"Kuwait", "Kuwait", "Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", 
"Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", 
"Taiwan", "Taiwan"), continent = c("Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia"
), year = c(1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 
1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 
1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 
2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 
1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 
1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 
2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L), lifeExp = c(60.96, 64.75, 
67.65, 70, 72, 73.6, 75.45, 76.2, 77.601, 80, 81.495, 82.208, 
44.869, 47.181, 49.325, 52.469, 55.234, 57.702, 59.62, 63.04, 
65.742, 68.042, 69.451, 70.964, 45.32, 48.437, 51.457, 54.459, 
56.95, 60.413, 62.038, 65.044, 59.461, 58.811, 57.046, 59.545, 
55.565, 58.033, 60.47, 64.624, 67.712, 69.343, 71.309, 74.174, 
75.19, 76.156, 76.904, 77.588, 39.875, 42.868, 45.914, 49.901, 
53.886, 58.69, 63.012, 66.295, 68.768, 70.533, 71.626, 72.777, 
60.396, 63.179, 65.798, 67.946, 69.521, 70.795, 71.76, 73.56, 
75.788, 77.158, 78.77, 79.972, 58.5, 62.4, 65.2, 67.5, 69.39, 
70.59, 72.16, 73.4, 74.26, 75.25, 76.99, 78.4), pop = c(2125900L, 
2736300L, 3305200L, 3722800L, 4115700L, 4583700L, 5264500L, 5584510L, 
5829696L, 6495918L, 6762476L, 6980412L, 17272000L, 19792000L, 
22874000L, 26538000L, 30614000L, 35480679L, 43072751L, 51889696L, 
60397973L, 63327987L, 66907826L, 69453570L, 5441766L, 6248643L, 
7240260L, 8519282L, 10061506L, 11882916L, 14173318L, 16543189L, 
17861905L, 20775703L, 24001816L, 27499638L, 160000L, 212846L, 
358266L, 575003L, 841934L, 1140357L, 1497494L, 1891487L, 1418095L, 
1765345L, 2111561L, 2505559L, 4005677L, 4419650L, 4943029L, 5618198L, 
6472756L, 8128505L, 11254672L, 14619745L, 16945857L, 21229759L, 
24501530L, 27601038L, 1127000L, 1445929L, 1750200L, 1977600L, 
2152400L, 2325300L, 2651869L, 2794552L, 3235865L, 3802309L, 4197776L, 
4553009L, 8550362L, 10164215L, 11918938L, 13648692L, 15226039L, 
16785196L, 18501390L, 19757799L, 20686918L, 21628605L, 22454239L, 
23174294L), gdpPercap = c(3054.421209, 3629.076457, 4692.648272, 
6197.962814, 8315.928145, 11186.14125, 14560.53051, 20038.47269, 
24757.60301, 28377.63219, 30209.01516, 39724.97867, 3035.326002, 
3290.257643, 4187.329802, 5906.731805, 9613.818607, 11888.59508, 
7608.334602, 6642.881371, 7235.653188, 8263.590301, 9240.761975, 
11605.71449, 4129.766056, 6229.333562, 8341.737815, 8931.459811, 
9576.037596, 14688.23507, 14517.90711, 11643.57268, 3745.640687, 
3076.239795, 4390.717312, 4471.061906, 108382.3529, 113523.1329, 
95458.11176, 80894.88326, 109347.867, 59265.47714, 31354.03573, 
28118.42998, 34932.91959, 40300.61996, 35110.10566, 47306.98978, 
6459.554823, 8157.591248, 11626.41975, 16903.04886, 24837.42865, 
34167.7626, 33693.17525, 21198.26136, 24841.61777, 20586.69019, 
19014.54118, 21654.83194, 2315.138227, 2843.104409, 3674.735572, 
4977.41854, 8597.756202, 11210.08948, 15169.16112, 18861.53081, 
24769.8912, 33519.4766, 36023.1054, 47143.17964, 1206.947913, 
1507.86129, 1822.879028, 2643.858681, 4062.523897, 5596.519826, 
7426.354774, 11054.56175, 15215.6579, 20206.82098, 23235.42329, 
28718.27684), Region = c("East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", 
"Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "Mid.East", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia", 
"East.Asia", "East.Asia", "East.Asia")), row.names = c(661L, 
662L, 663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 
721L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 730L, 731L, 
732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 741L, 742L, 
743L, 744L, 853L, 854L, 855L, 856L, 857L, 858L, 859L, 860L, 861L, 
862L, 863L, 864L, 1309L, 1310L, 1311L, 1312L, 1313L, 1314L, 1315L, 
1316L, 1317L, 1318L, 1319L, 1320L, 1357L, 1358L, 1359L, 1360L, 
1361L, 1362L, 1363L, 1364L, 1365L, 1366L, 1367L, 1368L, 1501L, 
1502L, 1503L, 1504L, 1505L, 1506L, 1507L, 1508L, 1509L, 1510L, 
1511L, 1512L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `std.error` from `plotrix` which can be used

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotrix)
df1 %>%
 group_by(year) %>%
 summarize(across(where( is.numeric),
   list(Mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), SE = std.error)), 
         .groups = 'drop' )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 7
#    year lifeExp_Mean lifeExp_SE  pop_Mean   pop_SE gdpPercap_Mean gdpPercap_SE
#   <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1  1952         52.2       3.27  5526101. 2231483.         18369.       15015.
# 2  1957         55.3       3.37  6431369  2552772.         19883.       15630.
# 3  1962         58.0       3.37  7484270. 2944533.         18543.       12879.
# 4  1967         61.0       3.17  8657082. 3409300.         18065.       10612.
# 5  1972         63.5       2.95  9926334. 3918016.         24907.       14289.
# 6  1977         65.9       2.52 11475236. 4508849.         21143.        7221.
# 7  1982         67.9       2.33 13773713. 5420634.         17761.        4012.
# 8  1987         70.2       1.99 16154425. 6521286.         16794.        2782.
# 9  1992         71.0       2.49 18053758. 7632907.         19357.        4195.
#10  1997         72.3       2.72 19860804. 7956987.         22047.        5024.
#11  2002         73.2       3.11 21562461. 8409880.         22461.        4675.
#12  2007         74.5       2.90 23109646. 8750833.         28661.        6431.
```